# help with folder style java gui

Tags: java, user-interface, using

i want to create a GUI from java.

i have created one but i want to make it more friendly so i need to change the way it looked.

i want to make it like textpad characteristic when u open new file or create new file,

the file will open beside your current file or in a same window right?
no new window for new file.its same with internet browser which allows us to open new tab in the same file.this is what i want but i dont want in applet,just desktop gui.

i want to pop up a result in the same frame without disturbing input form.

i'm thinking of popup window. but pop up window will popped out outside the frame.

what should i use?
is it possible to do?

please help me!!!

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers use what in Java would be a `JTabbedPane` to show multiple documents.

Old versions of TextPad (e.g. the one I am looking at is version 4.6.2 from 2003) used a list in the top left to select any of multiple documents to be shown on the right.  You could implement that in Java using a `JList` for the selector and a `CardLayout` for the documents.